# How do I replace a missing optional token with a default?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Imagine I have the following rules. I want to make `TYPE_ID` optional, but replace it with some default value in the AST if it is missing.

```
assignment : TYPE_ID? ID '->' expression 
TYPE_ID : ('A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')* ;
```

For example I have the following code to parse, given the above rules, assume that `expression` works as needed.

```
monday -> 1.
Number tuesday -> 2.
```

I want to have the AST have a *something* in front of `monday` in the tree in the same place that `Number` shows up in the next tree.

I have searched and searched and can't figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
tokens {
  EMPTY;
}

 assignment :   TYPE_ID ID  '->' expression -> ^( TYPE_ID ID '->' expression)
            |   ID          '->' expression -> ^( EMPTY ID '->' expression)
            ;
```

Comment: this works well, I just wonder if there is a less verbose way to achieve the same thing

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, no, there's no less verbose way, AFAIK. (although I don't find it too verbose, but that's just me...)