# How do I replace a missing optional token with a default value?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Given the rules:

```
list: 'LIST' code?;

code: 'CODE' CODE_VALUE;

CODE_VALUE: [0-9]+;
```

How can I set a default value for optional token `code` if not present?

The only similar question I could found is [How do I replace a missing optional token with a default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389475/how-do-i-replace-a-missing-optional-token-with-a-default), but it is 10 years old and tagged Antlr3.

Thanks.

Comment: Since Antlr4 does not have AST construction operators (and I am glad it does not), you would have to create an AST replacement for the parse tree in Antlr4 to create an tree node called "EMPTY". Alternatively, fold the `code?` expression into a new rule, e.g., `list: 'LIST' code_or_empty; code_or_empty: code | ;` which serves the same purpose as `^( EMPTY ...) | ^( TYPE_ID ...)` in the 10-y.o. question. But, it's unnecessary because you can test if `code` is a child of `list` very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ANTLR v3 there was a possibility to rewrite the parse tree into an abstract (syntax) tree. While doing so, one had the ability to "inject" tokens during this process. Since ANTLR v4 does not have this tree rewriting ability<sup>*</sup>, the answer to your question is: you cannot set a default value/token. My question to you: why do you need this? What use-case is there to inject a token?

<sup>*</sup> [theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/%7Eadmin/blog/2012/12/08/524353/Tree+rewriting+in+ANTLR+v4)

Comment: The use case would be avoiding `if (ctx.CODE() == null) { something } else { something else }` on listener/visitors. Of course, rules above are just an example. I thought there could be a way of defaulting values at parse level to avoid extra code. - I wonder if I should "go deeper" and use visitCode and somehow track context of which code I'm referring to. On a SQL example, `select c1 as alias1, c2 as alias2 ...` visitColumn and visitAlias, I'd need to keep track of which column I'm referring to when visitAlias is invoked.

Comment: You could just do something like `String code = ctx.CODE() == null ? "INJECTED_CODE" : ctx.CODE().getText();` and then `code` will always be non-null. Anyway, what you're asking for is not possible by rewriting/injecting a token in the grammar.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I currently have. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

This is a semantic task, not a syntactic one and parser are made to handle syntax. For any additional handling, which goes beyond the language syntax use the semantic phase after the parse phase, where you check for things like duplicate names, wrong types etc.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input, I'll research about it.